# Python3.4 memory usage

Tags: python, windows-7, garbage-collection, python-3.4

Consider those two codes, I run in the python console:

```
l=[]
for i in range(0,1000): l.append("."*1000000)
# if you check your taskmanager now, python is using nearly 900MB
del l
# now python3 immediately free-d the memory
```

Now consider this:

```
l=[]
for i in range(0,1000): l.append("."*1000000)
l.append(l)
# if you check your taskmanager now, python is using nearly 900MB
del l
# now python3 won't free the memory
```

Since I am working with those kind of objects, and I need to free them from my memory, I need to know in order to let python recognize it needs to delete the corresponding memory.

PS: I am using Windows7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've created a circular reference, the memory won't be freed until the garbage collector runs, detects the cycle, and cleans it up. [You can trigger that manually](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.collect):

```
import gc
gc.collect()  # Memory usage will drop once you run this.
```

The collector will automatically run occasionally, but only if [certain conditions related to the number of object allocations/deallocations are met](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold):

> **gc.set_threshold(threshold0[, threshold1[, threshold2]])**
>
> Set the garbage collection thresholds (the collection frequency).
>   Setting threshold0 to zero disables collection.
>
> The GC classifies objects into three generations depending on how many
>   collection sweeps they have survived. New objects are placed in the
>   youngest generation (generation 0). If an object survives a collection
>   it is moved into the next older generation. Since generation 2 is the
>   oldest generation, objects in that generation remain there after a
>   collection. **In order to decide when to run, the collector keeps track
>   of the number object allocations and deallocations since the last
>   collection. When the number of allocations minus the number of
>   deallocations exceeds threshold0, collection starts.**

So if you continued creating more objects in the interpreter, eventually the garbage collector would kick on by itself. You can make that happen more often by lowering `threshold0`, or you can just manually call `gc.collect` when you know you've deleted one of the objects containing a reference cycle.